# Android max number of instances of an Activity in back stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I can't seem to find any way to set a max number of instances of a single activity in the application. Essentially, what I want it to look like it if it had a max of 2 is:

A -> B -> B

And if the user tried to start another of the same activity, it replaces the most recent 'B' but leaves the first alone. However, if there is only one 'B', then just create a second 'B'. Only when there are two 'B' activities does it begin replacing 'B'.

There are plenty of options on making sure there is only 1 of the activity such as clear top and reorder front, but this doesn't seem possible. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Keep track of the number of B instances. When the user hits your maximum, and it's the point where you would normally start a new B, just update the content of the existing B (if it is in the foreground) or add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` (if it is not in the foreground). Or, only ever use one B, and use fragments and their back stack for your max-count tracking. Or, only ever use one B, and handle BACK events yourself.

Comment: Unless im wrong Activities are paused when not in use. i.e if you go to activity B activity A is Paused. I dont think you can have multiple runs of the same activity but you can copy them instead so there be clones of the same activity

Answer (score 0):

In general, creating multiple instances of an `Activity` is very difficult to manage, because you cannot address or return to any specific instance of the `Activity` using any of the `Intent` flags. I don't know your app or your requirements, but you should consider rearchitecting, using one of the following ideas:

- Don't create more than 1 instance of any activity. Use `Intent.FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to reuse an existing instance every time.
- Instead of starting `B` from `B`, just reuse the same instance of `B` and just change the data in it, giving the illusion that you are creating a new `Activity` (animation transition or whatever)
- Create a copy of the `Activity` (new class that extends existing class) and launch that instead, so that instead of having 2 instances of `B`, you have one instance of `B` and one instance of `CopyB`.